# How to update D3 contours with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, contour

I'm trying to update my d3js contours plot with new data. I'm using set interval method to create new random data and would like to generate new contours/animate current contours to new positions if that makes sense. Currently the code creates the contour plot for the fist data and doesn't update the contours with different data. Ideally, I would like to have a smooth transition of contours from one state to another according to the data I'm providing.

```js
values = []

function solve() {
  var svg = d3.select('svg'),
    svgWidth = +svg.attr('width'),

    n = 31, // data width
    m = 31 // data height



  var thresholds = d3.range(0, 1, 0.1);
  var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(thresholds))
    .interpolate(function() {
      return d3.interpolateCool;
    });


  svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(d3.contours()
      .size([n, m])
      .thresholds(thresholds)(values) // this will create 6 step

    )
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('d', d3.geoPath(d3.geoIdentity().scale(svgWidth / n)))
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return color(d.value);
    })
    .style('stroke', function(d) {
      return color(d.value);
    })
    .style('stroke-width', 2.5)
    .style('stroke-dasharray', '0, 1000');



  // march the contours into existence
  /*  svg.selectAll('path')
     .transition()
     .duration(1000)
   
     .style('stroke-dasharray', '1000, 0'); */
  return

}



function updateData() {
  for (var v = 0; v < 31 * 31; v++) {
    values[v] = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2))
  }
  return values
}

setInterval(function() {
  updateData()
  solve()

}, 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-contour.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>

<svg width="310" height="310" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-linecap="round">
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the idiomatic D3 "enter", "update" and "exit" selections. Here is your code refactored, the name of the selections are self-explanatory:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="310" height="310" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-linecap="round">
    </svg>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-contour.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    values = []

    updateData()
    solve();

    function solve() {
      var svg = d3.select('svg'),
        svgWidth = +svg.attr('width'),

        n = 31, // data width
        m = 31 // data height



      var thresholds = d3.range(0, 1, 0.1);
      var color = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(thresholds))
        .interpolate(function() {
          return d3.interpolateCool;
        });


      let paths = svg.selectAll('path')
        .data(d3.contours()
          .size([n, m])
          .thresholds(thresholds)(values) // this will create 6 step

        );

      const pathsExit = paths.exit().remove();

      const pathsEnter = paths.enter().append('path')
        .attr('d', d3.geoPath(d3.geoIdentity().scale(svgWidth / n)))
        .style('fill', function(d) {
          return color(d.value);
        })
        .style('stroke', function(d) {
          return color(d.value);
        })
        .style('stroke-width', 2.5)
        .style('stroke-dasharray', '0, 1000');

      paths = pathsEnter.merge(paths);

      paths.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('d', d3.geoPath(d3.geoIdentity().scale(svgWidth / n)))


      // march the contours into existence
      /*  svg.selectAll('path')
         .transition()
         .duration(1000)
       
         .style('stroke-dasharray', '1000, 0'); */
      return

    }



    function updateData() {
      for (var v = 0; v < 31 * 31; v++) {
        values[v] = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2))
      }
      return values
    }

    setInterval(function() {
      updateData()
      solve()

    }, 2000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, pay attention to the fact that this will only interpolate *the paths' d attribute*. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. 
"However, pay attention to the fact that this will only interpolate the paths' d attribute"
Idk what you mean by this one, I'm fairly new to d3js.

Comment: What I mean by that is simple: look at the transitions... they look terrible, not nice at all. For a nice transition you probably need a custom function, that better indicates how one contour turns into another.